# How to build a custom/different target in Yocto autotools projects?

Tags: yocto, autotools, bitbake, openbmc

I'm trying to use a 3rd-party autotools project in Yocto. Its unit tests are run by '`make check`' and requires '`./configure --enable-oe-sdk`', but this is not included in the default recipe (from autotools.bbclass). I want the tests built and run, so **How to build a different autoconf target in a Yocto/BitBake recipe?** Please note that the unit tests run on the development host, instead of running on the embedded target.

Here is what I have tried. [Adding extra options to recipes based on Autoconf](http://Adding%20extra%20options%20to%20recipes%20based%20on%20Autoconf). But it doesn't say how to build a different target. I added `EXTRA_OECONF += '--enable-oe-sdk'`, and tried to override do_compile() of the recipe. But got following error.

```
configure: error: OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT must be set with --enable-oe-sdk
```

I'm asking a generic question, but the project in question is [github.com/openbmc/phosphor-bmc-code-mgmt](https://github.com/openbmc/phosphor-bmc-code-mgmt/tree/6be275ba1ad1f3d45b2c2bf13dde7b4890f74f47/test). Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In openBMC's own repository, there is the **meta-phosphor** repository with the recipe ready for **[phosphor-bmc-code-mgmt.bb](https://github.com/openbmc/meta-phosphor/blob/gatesgarth/recipes-phosphor/flash/phosphor-software-manager_git.bb)**.

Clone and add meta-phosphor to **conf/bblayers.conf** and use the **phosphor-software-manager** recipe.

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to follow the recipe, but didn't see anything obvious. It's the right file and I will dig into it.

Answer (score 0):

I have run several openBMC test, but I am far from an expert.

It looks like the repo you are looking at was designed to be tested using the continues integration docker frame work.

The instruction on how to run the test are [here](https://github.com/openbmc/docs/blob/master/testing/local-ci-build.md) .
In the example they are testing "phosphor-hwmon" so insted try testing "phosphor-bmc-code-mgmt"

If that does not work, I bet the someone on openbmc discord will help you out. https://discord.com/invite/69Km47zH98

Comment: Thank you very much for the CI build suggestion. I must have overlooked it in the docs.